# Stellar full sync

Tags: stellar-core

I want to have full stellar history, but I can't. Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

I am trying to make full sync of Stellar test network. I have been trying to make several changes in the configuration, but none of them worked.

Some more details on what I have tried:

Build stellar core and horizon from source code and make catchup before running core.
stellar-core catchup 2 $last_ledger - 2

I set CATACHUP_RECENT to 2
I used the CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true environment variable
In all the cases my node is in sync, but the best result I achieved is to get elder_ledger as 50000 which doesn't look like a full sync. Or in some cases it shows something near newest ledger.

Thus, the question is if I am doing anything wrong or missed something?

Here my latest configs.

###CORE###

Docker image: stellar/stellar-core:15.1.0rc1-1405-90b27805

ENV variables:

env = [
"POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${random_password.stellar_core_postgres_password.result}",
"HORIZON_PASSWORD=${random_password.stellar_horizon_postgres_password.result}",
"compat_complete_PEER_PORT=11625",
"compat_complete_HTTP_PORT=11626",
"compat_complete_PEER_SEED=SBTEQJMDYCNRXRBEUUK7PTC737GVE24VSFVEHQXRALAARQCU5O246KVT",
"compat_complete_VALIDATION_SEED=SACTBO4KQ3LYYRRKBST3ZCO24FYRDP2CYN3W5IPP2OTC3NUIKFGZSRRY",
"CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true",
"PREFERRED_PEERS=["core-testnet1.stellar.org", "core-testnet2.stellar.org", "core-testnet3.stellar.org"]",
"UNSAFE_QUORUM=true",
"FAILURE_SAFETY=0",
"VALIDATORS=["GDKXE2OZMJIPOSLNA6N6F2BVCI3O777I2OOC4BV7VOYUEHYX7RTRYA7Y", "GCUCJTIYXSOXKBSNFGNFWW5MUQ54HKRPGJUTQFJ5RQXZXNOLNXYDHRAP", "GC2V2EFSXN6SQTWVYA5EPJPBWWIMSD2XQNKUOHGEKB535AQE2I6IXV2Z"]",
"HISTORY_PEERS=["core_testnet_001", "core_testnet_002", "core_testnet_003"]",
"HISTORY_GET=wget -q -O {1} https://history.stellar.org/prd/core-testnet/%s/{0}",
"NETWORK_PASSPHRASE=Test SDF Network ; September 2015"
]

CMD in Docker:

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/stellar-core", "run", "--conf", "/stellar-core.cfg”]

###HORIZON###

Entry point commands:

horizon_init_db

export LATEST_LADGER=$(curl -ks https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/ | jq .core_latest_ledger)

horizon db reingest range 0 $LATEST_LADGER

CMD in Docker

CMD ["horizon”]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please describe your issue in more detail. What behavior are you expecting and what behavior are you actually observing? If possible, provide the logs that point to your issue.